# Symfony 2.1 doctrine fixtures installation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1, composer-php

I am using latest symfony 2.1 and trying to install the doctrine fixture bundle.
I followed the instructions listed [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html).

Install composer and git as well. But now when I am trying to update the vendor libraries (`php composer.phar update`) I am getting the following error:

Loading composer repositories with package information

```
Updating dependencies
  - Removing doctrine/dbal (2.3.0)
vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine - The directory is not empty.
 [RuntimeException]
  Could not completely delete vendor/doctrine/dbal,
   aborting.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Did u put the line of json to download inside the "require"? Do you have any other "require" key in the json?

Comment: I suppose that you have to remove all files from target directory. He tries to remove a folder but he can't do it recursively so it fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when a package directory in the vendor dir is locked for some reason by another application. This tends to happen on windows where many things can lock a directory/file.

If it's an intermittent issue, running composer update should fix it, but if it persists try to remove `vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine` by hand.

If it is really locked you won't be able to delete it either unless you close anything locking that dir. Using [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) can assist you if you have no idea what is holding a lock over the directory.

Comment: Thanks, I run update command after closing all application and It works!